# Weird URL encryption/decryption, how does this work?

Tags: javascript, url, encryption, video-streaming, jwplayer

This URL is meant for embedding: http://www.filenuke.net/go/7c4cfe1c025c22e07665fe95e50b263f
The sourcecode is only 18 lines.

Using httpfox I already found out, that the video URL is: `http://cs523208v4.vk.me/u228522613/videos/cf627b7f78.360.mp4` and that it comes from this file: `http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=228522613&id=167539322&hash=fe2eee245277a903`

I guess, that the proxy.link in the Flashvars is the `http://vk.com/video_ext.php...` in encrypted from.
But it just looks like this:  `fnk*06eef539920cbb86d4b1aee311b4e2199ec45f17008efbf9e013d3c0c6e74babdb407497b40a4600b794bc1e55179e930eaf895ba9c747735cbf8163b9b8b53e43e0b66e4e71df2d563b2aea2b00a2ec`
... "fnk" is no valid variable, so how exactly is the URL gererated/decrypted?

I hope you can help me, I'd really appreciate it.

edit: It must have something to do with these files:

```
http://www.filenuke.net/plugins/proxy.swf
http://www.filenuke.net/plugins/pluginslist.xml
http://www.filenuke.net/plugins/gkplugins_license.swf?embedallow=nowvideo.ws,sharesix.net,putlocker.ws,movshare.me,novamov.me,sockshare.ws,watchfreeinhd.com,letmewatchthis2k.com
http://www.filenuke.net/plugins/gkplugins_encode.swf
http://www.filenuke.net/plugins/gkplugins_vk.swf?quality=720p&boxmenu=true
```

Is there any chance at all to get the video URL without running Flash?

Comment: This site is using a plugin from GKPlugins, which sells plugins for stealing streams.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I could reverse engineer the system? 
I couldn't really find anything in proxy.swf and gkplugins_license.swf.. And showmycode.com wasn't able to decompile gkplugins_encode.swf and gkplugins_vk.swf. :/

Comment: There are swf decompilers out there, but they just give you the ActionScript source code, it won't be helpful unless you know ActionScript. Are you just trying to download their videos?

Comment: Well, I know many scripting/programming languages, so understanding ActionScript per se is not a problem, I'm just not familiar with it's structure and have to look up some commands.  
I'm also not just trying to download their videos, (I could simply do that with the Firefox dev tools), I'm trying to write a program/script myself, that can extract the video URLs from this site as efficiently as possible, without running flash.

Comment: I would look into a swf decompiler then for trying to get the sources to these plugins.

Comment: forivin did you find a solution for extracting yet ? i am trying to do same but no luck so far!

Comment: @user1788736 Nope, I pretty much gave up. :/